# Lists in dictionary using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create new dataframe out of the dictionary which includes lists.

It looks like something like that:

```
{'prices': [[1574121600000, 1.000650588888066], [1574208000000, 0.9954110116644869]...
```

Those are UNIX date and price of stablecoins, however the columns are not named properly as it is all under 'prices' key.

However how could I create a new df which would include 2 columns (Date, Price) using values from this dictionary?

My goal is to get something like this:

```
| Date             | Price |
| 15741216000000   | 1.000650588888066   |
| 15742080000000   | 0.9954110116644869   |
```

Comment: just create the frame from the prices key: `df = pd.DataFrame(d['prices'], columns=['Date', 'Price'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) directly and then pass a list of column names to the parameter `columns`

```
import pandas as pd

a = {'prices': [[1574121600000, 1.000650588888066], [1574208000000, 0.9954110116644869]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(a['prices'], columns=['Date', 'Price'])
print(df)
# prints
            Date     Price
0  1574121600000  1.000651
1  1574208000000  0.995411
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'prices': [[1574121600000, 1.000650588888066], [1574208000000, 0.9954110116644869]}
df = {"date":[],"prices":[]}
for k,v in d.items():
    for item in v:
        df["date"].append(item[0])
        df["prices"].append(item[1])
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df)
```